# Unable to create Vpnservice

Tags: java, android, service, android-vpn-service

I am a beginner, I am having trouble using VpnService.

> Bad prefixLength  Caused by: android.net.VpnService$Builder.addAddress(VpnService.java:496)

The above is the error log.

```java
Builder builder = new Builder();
builder.addAddress("211.147.226.4", 8118);
builder.setSession(getString(R.string.app_name));
builder.setConfigureIntent(pendingIntent);
vpnInterface = builder.establish();
```

This is my code.

My ip address is ipv4 but I don't know why an error occurred. I need help. Thank you for your help.

Comment: second parameter in `addAddress` is not the port, it is prefix length.

Comment: Hello, how to get the prefix length?

Comment: You should know it. You can try 32.

Comment: How to add an address while setting the address? @VladyslavMatviienko

Answer (score 0):

netmask is error change  8118 to 24
builder.addAddress("211.147.226.4", 24);